# Finding and replacing the absolute maximum postive and negative in a python dataframe

Tags: python

I have a data frame of values in python an example is given below

```
   A        B       C      
 -0.9      0.6    -1.1  
  0.7     -0.4    -0.2     
   1        2       3
  -1       -2      -3
```

What I would like to do is to replace the element with 1 if the absolute maximum is positive and -1 if the absolute maximum is negative and the other elements would be zero. so the above example would convert to

```
       A   B   C      
       0   0  -1 
       1   0   0  
       0   0   1
       0   0  -1
```

is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "absolute maximum"?

Comment: How can absolute maximum be negative?

Comment: What do mean with data frame? a dictionary?

Comment: You can't do this with a single query.  You will have to process this row by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that applies a helper function to the dataframe:

```
def helper(row):
    m =max(abs(row))
    for col in df.columns:
        if abs(row[col]) == m:
            if row[col] > 0:
                row[col] = 1
            elif row[col] < 0:
                row[col] = -1
        else:
            row[col] = 0
    return row

df = df.apply(helper,axis = 1).astype(int)

print(df)
#output:
   A  B  C
0  0  0 -1
1  1  0  0
2  0  0  1
3  0  0 -1
```